# Should the threshold for suggesting tag synonyms be lowered?

Tags: discussion, support, tagging

I believe the current rep threshold for suggesting tag synonyms is 2500. That's excessive for our current site, and I think aliases can be quite useful. Should we try to get the admins to lower the threshold for (the private, and maybe also the open) beta?

I suggest we try and form an opinion by voting for a "yes" and a "no" answer, which I'll create as community wiki so that I don't get any rep for the votes.

Comment: This is a standard feature on StackExchange for a good reason.

Comment: Typically (on other metas) people just up or downvote the question itself to indicate agreement; meta questions don't generate rep for exactly this reason (amongst others), so CW doesn't matter. Posting yes/no answers gives people multiple votes

Comment: I think after the first week or so we will have mods and they can begin the cleanup.

Comment: @Michael: makes sense. Won't do it again. I guess I can't easily take it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, don't lower it.  This will be solved whenever we get some pro-tem Moderators.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's one of the first things pro-tem mods do (add synonyms and merge tags)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

No, this would be a bad idea.